# How to make dist klasor, angular?

Tags: angular, webpack, bundle

[image]

How can I make this klasor work, without ng serve ?

Because I need to upload a html file and it should be plain. I want to get rid of selectors such as, `<app-root>`. Is this possible, or is there a way that to make this selectors work when I packed the azure-web-extension as ####.vsix

Should I need to known about bundles and webpack etc. ?

Comment: do you want to extend the angular webpack to suite your needs, to a custom webpack configuration that would allow such a  klasor ? or you just want to serve the dist/time-sheet folder onto a server without ng serve ?

Comment: I want to upload dist klasor to the server and to see the content properly

Comment: Actually, now I upload the dist klasor, and I suppose my new problem is the following error which I see in console page of the browser **Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**